# How to interpret Emmeans results

Tags: statistical-significance, interpretation, lsmeans, differences

I have used the emmeans() package to calculated the difference between the difference of estimated marginal means. I did this by first calculating the EMMs of location|treatment, and then the difference of the EMMs near-far. Then, I calculated the difference of the differences below:

Here is the output:

```
# contrast                                          estimate    SE  df t.ratio p.value
# near - far,constant - near - far,pulsed_nofood       1.003 0.534 124 1.878   0.1475 
# near - far,pulsed_food - near - far,pulsed_nofood    1.698 0.625 124 2.718   0.0201 
# near - far,pulsed_food - near - far,constant         0.695 0.510 124 1.363   0.3604  
# 
# Results are given on the log (not the response) scale.
# P value adjustment: mvt method for 3 tests
```

One difference is significantly different than another (pulsed with food, near-far to pulsed with no food, near-far). But pulsed with food, near-far, is not significantly different than constant, near-far, and constant is not significantly different than pulsed with no food, near-far.

I'm trying to interpret the results and finding it tricky since pulsed with food is significantly different than pulsed with no food, but it isn't significantly different than constant and constant isn't significantly different than pulsed with no food.

It's a mouthful, but any guidance would be greatly appreciated!